# App requirements for Windows Store

Tags: windows-store

Is it possible to publish a Windows Desctop Application to Windows Store? Or does it have to be a Windows Store Application?

I am asking because the Windows store app is too limited and I would like to add an ordinary Windows application to the store but don't know if it is possible.

[image: Windows application in Visual Studio]

BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Windows 10, the Windows Store will support more than just traditional Windows Store apps. There will be support for Win32 applications in the Windows Store.

Take a look at this video from the Build 2015 conference that talks about "All That is New with the Windows Store"

- https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-664

Also check out the following page on Universal Windows Bridges, specifically on Win32 desktop applications for the Windows Store.

- https://dev.windows.com/en-US/uwp-bridges/

As of August 2015, the above website says that it will be available next year (i.e. 2016):

> "The Windows Bridge for Classic Windows apps (also called ”Project
>   Centennial”) will make it possible to package and publish your current
>   .NET and Win32-based Windows applications to the Windows Store,
>   providing a new way of distributing and monetizing your application on
>   Windows PCs.
>
> In addition to packaging your application for Store distribution, the
>   Windows Bridge for Classic Windows apps will also enable you to extend
>   your application with UWP capabilities and APIs.
>
> The Windows Bridge for Classic Windows apps will be made available for
>   public testing next year."

Answer (score 0):

no you cannot publish simple applicaion to windows store. it has to be windows store application ...